# Taking multiple inputs from people

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just started using python programming and i know that if you use

```
raw_input("enter a letter")
```

It would ask the user for an input. How would I ask for multiple inputs. So if i wanted it to consist of three people asking them to enter a letter. Example person1 picks letter "a", person2 picks letter "b", person3 picks letter "c".

Would i simply just put

```
person1 = raw_input("enter a letter")

person2 = raw_input("enter a letter")

person3 = raw_input("enter a letter")
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, something like below so you can easily change number of user inputs

```
n = 3
user_input = []
for i in range(n):
     user_input.append(raw_input('User {} enter a letter:'.format((i + 1)).strip())
```